# Assistance needed with parsing a 32-bit flag

Tags: bit-manipulation, reverse-engineering

I'm working with a 32bit signed int, that should contain true/false flags for 24+ items, starting with an id of 1. So my first assumption was that each bit corresponds to its corresponding item item id. So to start off, I simply did

```
(flag_int >> item_id) & 1
```

And this worked - mostly. For example, starting with a flag int of 125831406, the expected result(left) compared to the  actual result (right)

```
1  true   true
2  true   true
3  true   true
4  false  false
5  true   true
6  true   true
7  true   true
8  false  false
9  false  false
10 false  false
11 false  true <<
.. ???    false
22 true  false <<
23 ???    true
24 true   true
25 true   true
26 true   true
```

The trouble is, not every flag ends up with known discrepancies, and when it does, it's not always on the same id, and the number of discrepancies always seems to vary between 1 and 2.

So this tells me there's some other value at play. The good news is that there's two possibilities that I know of. First, is the entry id - which in the example is 307, and second is an additional 0/1 flag, which in the example would be 1.

The bad news is, that I'm woefully deficient in bitwise operations when it comes to flags, and my attempts have been all for naught. So while I certainly don't expect the "right" answer, some ideas on what to try would be most appreciated.

Comment: To clarify: you have a collection of predefined flags, and you're trying to interpret their values, yes? Could you share the actual flag values with us?

Comment: @Rook he did, 125831406

Comment: @harold yeah, I said that incorrectly. I meant to ask about the _expected_ values (the left hand column).

Comment: @Digital_Utopia how did you construct this value?

Comment: The expected values were taken from observing how the application (game) itself uses these flags. So, for the available item_ids, the expected values are the ones I should arrive at, if I've processed the flags correctly

Comment: Could they have inverted meanings?

Comment: Nah, see - it's not just that one example either. Here's my data so far on what I've checked, with that same bitmask. It's just too similar to be fundamentally wrong, but I'm obviously missing something...

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MNDgjMiVp5v6jc5no8OFFbHxg98b4E5dhPb4-hPNKUs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of these flags was to determine whether or not certain parts of a character should be hidden, by the type of headwear they were wearing. Each ID identified a character type, and each item had two Flag IDs - one for each gender.

To avoid any extra variables - I elected to use the "Ears" flag - because unlike hair, or other parts, it should've been the easiest to spot, with the lowest chance of additional complexity. I mean, every character has ears, and only one style of ears - so it should've been pretty binary.

The discrepancies - despite how much time I spent making sure I was getting the most accurate results, were embarrassingly easy to explain - because it had nothing to do with the flags, and everything to do with the traits of these characters.

One character type of each gender would ignore their flag, because their ears were part of the base mesh, and couldn't be hidden.

two more character types- both genders, seemed to defy their flag, only because their ears weren't considered ears, so their display would be handled by a different flag.

So anyway, that was the problem. If I would've simply taken another look at the mesh of those character types, I would've saved myself a ton of time.